# How to make custom Intellisense for a word in a richtextbox for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, richtextbox, intellisense

I was wondering if anyone knew how to create a intellisense type form for a rich text box word. Really I only need help with the code that gets the highlighted words location and places my form under the word to the left.

For example: When I highlight a word in my RichTextBox and click on a button, a form of my choice would popup under the word to the left.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqTux.png)

thank for anyone that can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a great example on code project :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180311/Rich-Text-Box-With-Intellisense-Ability

[image: Intellisense-Ability]

Answer (score 1):

This is a another codeproject example but winforms not WPF like amen ayach example:

[DIY Intellisense](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5839/DIY-Intellisense)

[image: DIY Intellisense]

Comment: **Though this is fairly old.. You should include a solution by not _only_ providing a link, but displaying the solution _here_. The link may at some point become invalid, and then the solution will be lost.**